# Showing Image and uploading the image problem

Tags: php, html

I having a problem getting image and store them in database

The problem is it's showing that pimage is Undefined and the image I choose is not storing in the database

This is the Image when I try to submit it to show you what the problem is
[image: submit]

This is my database look like
[image: database]

It's not storing my image

```php
$fol = $_POST['folder'];
$lin = $_POST['link'];
$target_dir="image/";
$target_file=$target_dir.basename($_FILES['pimage']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name'],$target_file);

if(empty($fol)){
    echo "<div class='alert-danger'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle'>
    <strong>Please Enter Folder Name</strong>
    </i></div>";
} 
if(empty($lin)) {
    echo "<div class='alert-danger'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle'>
    <strong>Please Enter Link</strong>
    </i></div>";
} 
else{
    $sql="SELECT id FROM filelink WHERE folder_name ='$fol' LIMIT 1";
    $check_query =mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count_folder = mysqli_num_rows($check_query);

    if($count_folder>0){
        echo "<div class='alert-danger'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle'>
        <strong>Sorry Folder Name Already Exist</strong>
        </i></div>";
    }
    else{
        $sql ="INSERT INTO filelink(link,folder_name,folder_image)VALUES('$lin','$fol','$target_file')";
        $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        if($run_query){
            echo "<div class='alert-success'>
            <strong>Add File Successful Refresh Page to see Change</strong></i>
            </div>";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="/action_page.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-container">
     <div id="e_msg" style="font-size: 13; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 15px;">
                     <!-- message for adding file if success-->
    </div>
      <label for="folder"><b>Folder</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Folder Name" name="folder" required>

      <label for="link"><b>Link</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Link" name="link" required>

    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" name="pimage" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" required>
        <label for ="customFile" class="custom-file-label">Choose Product Image</label>
    </div>

      <button style="margin-top: 15px;" type="submit" class="btn btnsub">Submit</button>
      <a href="file.php" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Which PHP file have you posted? `addfile.php` (which the error in the screen shot comes from) or `action_page.php`, which you post the form to? It seems like you have more than one issue here.

Comment: You are also _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks. _Never_ inject user data directly into your queries like that. Use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with bound parameters instead. It's also not just about security. If your queries contains certain characters, it can break your query. You should start by sorting this out since it will require you to rewrite how you store the data in the database (which could result in you fixing the issue). No need to debug code that needs to be rewritten asap anyway.

Comment: Hai Mr Magnus the one i posted is addfile. php i have no action.php sorry for misleading i will change the code

Comment: Start by fixing the other urgent issue I pointed out instead since that will require you to rewrite parts of your existing code anyway.